# Get current cell value from open Excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have an open instance of Excel *which is already connected to via a COM process*, which I have changed the value of one of the cells. In C# I can't get a connection to the sheet, but in python i can

Working Python code:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('c:/users/me/Desktop/mysheet.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
print(sheet.range('B1').value) # returns the current value
```

Non-working C# code:

```
var xlApp = (Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
Workbook wb = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook; // returns null
Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
string test = excelSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString();
```

Is there a way to get C# to connect to this sheet, given it is already open via a COM automation from another software product?

Most of the online discussion around GetActiveObject is to talk to a specific instance of Excel if there are multiple instances running, I have the opposite problem, a single instance of Excel and multiple applications trying to connect to it.

Comment: Your code runs fine on my setup. I get the current value using Excel 2016 (desktop version, not Office 365). I did try with and without `xlApp.Visible = true;`, which made no difference. What version of Excel are you running? Are there any other processes that could be interfering?

Comment: Yes there is another process writing to the sheet, probably also using COM, It turned out in my tests there was a second instance of Excel which was returning me the 'saved' value. Closing this second instance means i can now no longer connect to the sheet i want to (.ActiveWorkbook is null).  Is there a way to open a 'shared' connection to the sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Workbook wb = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(@"c:\users\me\Desktop\mysheet.xlsx") as Workbook;
```

should get the workbook even if it is already opened in Excel or not.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eric_carter/2009/03/12/attaching-to-an-already-running-office-application-from-your-application-using-getactiveobject-or-bindtomoniker/